# What does it mean for a "baseband" signal to be a signal near zero frequency range?

Tags: signal-processing, amplitude-modulation

I'm trying to understand the intuition and math of "baseband." Wiki says it is a signal near zero frequency range. Don't all signals of any type need a frequency otherwise they are not a signal? By definition an electromagnetic wave has a frequency, so I thought.

The next mystery is that wiki says the signal is near the y axis. An example I read is "telephone signal." In what sense does a telephone signal jump up and down the y axis and at the same time is near zero in frequency?

My motivation here is to learn AM and the word "baseband" keeps appearing as I read so need to undertand the lingo of baseband first. One hurdle at a time.

Comment: Baseband signal is usually modulated on a carrier signal, which is high frequency. So there is no situation that there is no signal. Here is a better definition for your purposes I guess: https://techterms.com/definition/baseband

Comment: "near zero" means (as an example) audio frequencies in comparison to the carrier freq in the MHz or even GHz range

Comment: my last comment (removed) was intended to a different question

Comment: @Eugene Sh. yes that will do very nicely. Much better than wiki. thank you

Comment: @Brian Drummond...ahhh... the other signals are that much faster...makes sense. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally 'baseband' means the signal that you actually use, so an audio baseband would be 20 Hz to 20 kHz, and a telephone baseband would be 300 Hz to 3400 Hz. The bandwidth ratio, highest/lowest frequency, tends to be much larger than 1. Often a baseband signal will also contain DC, in which case a bandwidth ratio is meaningless.

If the baseband signal is transmitted by modulating it onto a carrier, then the resulting signal will generally be 'narrowband', it will have a bandwidth ratio very close to 1. An audio signal AM modulated onto 1 MHz carrier would have a frequency range from 980 kHz to 1020 kHz, practically a single frequency in ratio terms.